# Подсчёт количества строк в таблице - результате запроса SHOW INDEX

Tags: mysql, индексы

Запрос

```
SHOW INDEX FROM `table_name` WHERE KEY_NAME = 'index_name'
```

возвращает таблицу. Почему я не могу вывести количество строк в этой таблице следующим запросом?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SHOW INDEX FROM `table_name` WHERE KEY_NAME = 'index_name');
```

Это неправильный запрос, или в принципе невозможно вывести количество строк в таблице - результате запроса `SHOW INDEX`?

Comment: SHOW не является оператором DML (управления данными) и не может использоваться в запросах

Comment: @Mike, а подобной команды, которая показывает, есть ли индекс в таблице, и является оператором DML, в MySQL нет?

Comment: Наверное, только запрос - обращение к БД information_schema?...

Comment: Да, только обращением information_schema